# Is this question too broad for this stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

The question I am asking about: [Pathfinder Magic Item Crafter Build Guide](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41773/pathfinder-magic-item-crafter-build-guide)

Normally I would have just voted to close the question and moved on, but since there is an open bounty on the question I cannot vote.

This question covers a lot of stuff: skills, feats, traits, races and classes (possibly more just not currently address by question body and answers).  The only answer covers over 6 full screen lengths for my desktop pc.

The vote to close description for 'too broad' says the following (emphasis mine):

> There are either too many possible answers, or **good answers would be
>   too long for this format**. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to **isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs**.

Is this type of question/answer not too broad for our site? If it does not fall under the 'answer are too long for our format' umbrella, how long of and answer do we need to have that condition trigger?

Answer (score 5):

The question *might* be a bit broad. And that answer sure is long, but let's look at what the question is actually asking for:

> Is there a guide anywhere that I may have missed outlining recommended traits, feats and such for a magic item crafter in Pathfinder?

That's looking for a resource, not a full guide. The fact that the answerer chose to *provide the guide* rather than simply point the OP at a link or two to a guide simply means he's gone the extra mile.

In this case the breadth of the question is not the prompt for the answer, but the answerer's own initiative.

Comment: Which leads to a follow-up question - is the *answer* inappropriate for the site?

Comment: @lisardggY it *could* be Not an answer...but...it's a valuable enough contribution that I'd let it slide

Comment: @lisardggY Also, that can be remedied by adding "Yes, right here" to the top of the answer. This wouldn't actually improve the answer in any way other than making it actually answer the question, and would arguably be very silly.

Comment: @MrLemon Noting that you can find one here is good, but what it really needs is some indication that the answerer was unable to find another one (or links to the ones that were found).